# Class not found - PSR-4 namespaced autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I wanted to set up PSR-4 autoloading for a class I wrote. However I keep getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'Glowdemon1\Translxtor\LangParserXML' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\translator\index.php on line 5`

Folder structure(can't post img yet):

[image]

LangParserXML.class.php

```
namespace Glowdemon1\Translxtor;
class LangParserXML extends ErrorHandler implements ParserInterface{
...
```

index.php

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$translator = new Glowdemon1\Translxtor\LangParserXML('nl.xml');
```

composer.json

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Glowdemon1\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

autoload_psr4.php

```
return array(
    'Glowdemon1\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
);
```

I have looked trough countless posts, yet no solutions. This is also posted on https://github.com/glowdemon1/translxtor in case you want a deeper look. Thanks.

Comment: Composer `ps-4` should be `Glowdemon1\\Translxtor\\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates your composer.json to :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Glowdemon1\\Translxtor\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Or add a `src/Transxtor/` directory before your `LangParserXMl`

Also, your filename cannot contain ".class". It should just be called `LangParserXML.php`.

Comment: Thank's for the improvement @Evert

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a `Translxtor` folder within `src` containing `LangParserXML.class.php` and  `Translator.class.php`:

> The contiguous sub-namespace names after the "namespace prefix" correspond to a subdirectory within a "base directory", in which the namespace separators represent directory separators. The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.

Source: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
`